# Zendesk: How can I get unread message count in iOS?

Tags: ios, zendesk

I search in it's develop document, but didn't find the method.

https://develop.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001687168-How-can-I-get-unread-message-count-related-to-tickets-in-android-and-iOS

The link is too old to get useful solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the method:

```
ZDKRequestProvider().getUpdatesForDevice { requestUpdates in
    
}
```